# Denormalizing annual table

Tags: sql, sql-server, denormalization

I have a table that contains information about annual sales with the date being the last date of the year. So the schema looks like:

```
endOfYearDate | metric1 | ... | metricN
```

I want to denormalize this table to have one row for each day of the year with the data for that row coming from the original row for that year. So the metrics will all be duplicated, but the `date` will be different.

```
dailyDate | metric1 | ... | metricN
```

Is there a SQL query to do this easily?

Comment: Could you please explain how?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (endOfYearDate date,metric1 int,metric2 int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2014-12-31',10,25),
('2015-12-31',35,50),
('2016-12-31',200,250)

;with cteMinMax As (
                    Select MinDate=DateAdd(YY,-1,min(endOfYearDate)) 
                          ,MaxDate=DateAdd(YY, 1,max(endOfYearDate)) 
                          ,Days   =DateDiff(DD,DateAdd(YY,-1,min(endOfYearDate)),DateAdd(YY, 1,max(endOfYearDate))) 
                     From @YourTable
      )
     ,cte0(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
     ,cteD(D)   As (Select Top (Select Days from cteMinMax) cast(DateAdd(DD,Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)),(Select MinDate from cteMinMax)) as date) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3, cte0 N4, cte0 N5, cte0 N6)
Select Date=D 
      ,B.*
 From cteD A
 Join @YourTable B on Year(endOfYearDate)=Year(D)
 Order By D
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Thanks John this is what I was going for in my comment, yours works so +1, though because your tally table was into the millions it took about 9 seconds on my personal laptop.  Limiting your tally and working off the dayofyear will make it a little more lean

Comment: @Matt 9 seconds!  My laptop between 0.307 and 0.378

Comment: yeah 9 seconds on first run subsequent executions where less than a second due to cached execution plans.  I am on i5, 8 GB RAM, and SSD that read writes at close to 1 GB per second

Comment: @Matt Thanks to your comments, I added some min/max to constraints to the query.  Execution time is down to 0.115 seconds on a clean/re-booted machine.  Seeing the same performance on your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Tally Table, a table with a row for each integer between 1 and N you can then use the DATEPART(dayofyear,endOfYearDate) to join on.  Note that the tally table really only has to have 366 values for leap years.  And using this method actually works with leap years as well.

```
Declare @YourTable table (endOfYearDate date,metric1 int,metric2 int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2014-12-31',10,25),
('2015-12-31',35,50),
('2016-12-31',200,250)


;WITH cte AS (Select 1 as N From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
,cteTally AS (
    SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
       cte n
       CROSS JOIN cte n2
       CROSS JOIN cte n3
)

SELECT
    DATEADD(day,- t.Number + 1, yt.endOfYearDate) as Date
    ,yt.endOfYearDate 
    ,yt.metric1
    ,yt.metric2
FROM
    @YourTable yt
    INNER JOIN cteTally t
    ON DATEPART(dayofyear,yt.endOfYearDate) >= t.Number
ORDER BY
    Date
```

@John basically embodied what I wanted to write before I came back here but by using DAYOFYEAR instead of generating all of the dates means the tally table is significantly smaller and performs a lot faster.

As far as a Date dimmension.  I and many others actually materialize a date table to work with it makes a lot of joins etc much easier and if you have one all you have to do is an inner join to get to your desired results.  Microsoft SSAS will generate one for you or you can build a script to build your own.

And here is one way of doing a recursive cte.  you will notice I had to set the max levels of recursion to 365 (366 - 1).

```
;WITH cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT endOfYearDate as Date, DATEPART(dayofyear,endOfYearDate) as DOY, endOfYearDate, metric1, metric2
    FROM
       @YourTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       DATEADD(day,-1,Date)
       ,DOY - 1
       ,endOfYearDate
       ,metric1
       ,metric2
    FROM
       cteRecursive
    WHERE
       DOY - 1 > 0
)

SELECT Date, endOfYearDate, metric1, metric2
FROM
    cteRecursive
ORDER BY
    Date
OPTION (maxrecursion 365)
```